# App Store doesn't fetch updates anymore

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

I'm on a MacBook Pro, mid 2009, OS X 10.10.

An update to Yosemite (10.10.2) came out five days ago, but going to the Updates tab in App Store only returns a dialog box with the following message:

```
An error has occurred
Can't connect to the Apple Software Update server.
```

I have turned off Firewall, logged out/in from App Store, removed App Store cookies - but despite this and after googling over an hour I'm still clueless.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to troubleshoot this - I would do the following:

1. Make a new admin account on the Mac and restart.
2. Log in to the new account (you might have to disable auto login for the old account)
3. Open Console.app and look over two log files

   - /var/log/install.log
   - /var/log/commerce.log
4. Open System Preferences (while watching the logs above) and unselect all of the App Store options. Turn off "Automatically check for updates"
5. Run the App Store App - click Purchases - sign in to the App Store.

At this point you should have dozens of log fie entries that may point to a network error, a certificate error, an account error or perhaps a permissions problem.

The App Store app is basically a web browser that runs some code, interacts with several servers and needs date/time/encryption certificates to be correct to function properly.

You also might consider installing a clean OS onto a USB drive to boot to it and do the tests if you have any security/firewall software you don't want to uninstall / disable on the main Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of *possible* solutions here:

1. Repair permissions and retry.

If it won't work:

2. Delete (consider doing a backup before) your `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist` and `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist` files and try again.